# How to rotate the image frame?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

```
convert 'a.png' \
\( -background none -geometry 100x100+150+50! -rotate 5 'b.png' \) \
-composite 'a.png';
```

This is a simple script to rotate and place an image `b` on top of image `a`. My problem is that image `b` is being rotated within the defined area (100x100):

[image: bad]

How do I rotate the whole image frame as such:

[image: good]

Or, put it simple:

[image]

1. is the original picture (a) with (b) picture on top of it
2. picture two is how im rotates the (b) picture
3. is how I need the picture rotated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help from Freenode community, here is the answer:

```
convert 'a.png' \( 'b.png' -resize 100x100 -rotate 50 \) -geometry +100+50 -composite 'a.png';
```

The problem was that `-geometry` restricted the rotated element to the specified dimensions.